# How to make sure FindRelatedProducts runs after the UI was shown using WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a MSI installer and I specify per-machine installation in the installer UI. Previous version was also installed per-machine.

However, FindRelatedProducts reports that current install is per-user.

`MSI (c) (A4:F0) [13:33:20:490]: FindRelatedProducts: **current install is per-user**.  Related install for product '<<my guid>>' is per-machine.  Skipping...`

From the log I can see that `ALLUSERS` property is created only after FindRelatedProducts ran (note timestamp):

`MSI (c) (A4:A8) [13:33:25:032]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ALLUSERS property. Its value is '2'.`

The property ALLUSERS is `Published` from the UI based on what the user selected:

```
      <Publish Property="ALLUSERS" Value="2"><![CDATA[FolderForm_AllUsers="ALL" AND VersionNT>=400 AND Privileged=1 AND FolderForm_AllUsersVisible=1]]></Publish>
      <Publish Property="ALLUSERS" Value="{}"><![CDATA[FolderForm_AllUsers="ME" AND VersionNT>=400 AND Privileged=1 AND FolderForm_AllUsersVisible=1]]></Publish>


    <Control Id="AllUsersRadioGroup" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="20" Y="175" Width="342" Height="42" Property="FolderForm_AllUsers" Text ="empty">      
      <RadioButtonGroup Property="FolderForm_AllUsers">
        <RadioButton Value="ALL" X="0" Y="0" Width="342" Height="17" Text="$(loc.InstallForAll)" />
        <RadioButton Value="ME" X="0" Y="18" Width="342" Height="17" Text="$(loc.InstallForMe)" />
      </RadioButtonGroup>

      <Condition Action="show"><![CDATA[VersionNT>=400 AND Privileged=1 AND FolderForm_AllUsersVisible=1]]></Condition>
      <Condition Action="hide"><![CDATA[NOT (VersionNT>=400 AND Privileged=1 AND FolderForm_AllUsersVisible=1)]]></Condition>
    </Control>
```

As a result, the new version is installed alongside the existing (two entries exist in Add/Remove programs).

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="VSDCA_FolderForm_AllUsers" After="IsolateComponents"><![CDATA[Installed="" AND NOT RESUME AND ALLUSERS=1]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="PreventDowngrading" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWPRODUCTFOUND</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>


<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <!-- Only schedule this custom action for the 32-bit MSI.  -->
  <?if $(var.DependenciesPlatform)=x86 ?>
  <Custom Action="CA_Err32BitMsiOn64BitOS" After="LaunchConditions">
    <![CDATA[MsiAMD64 OR Intel64]]>
  </Custom>
  <?endif ?>

  <!-- Prevent downgrading -->
  <Custom Action="PreventDowngrading" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWPRODUCTFOUND</Custom>

  <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />

  <Custom Action="LaunchApp" After="InstallFinalize" />

  <InstallInitialize></InstallInitialize>
  <RemoveShortcuts></RemoveShortcuts>
  <InstallFiles></InstallFiles>
  <CreateShortcuts></CreateShortcuts>
  <InstallFinalize></InstallFinalize>

  <ScheduleReboot After="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This occurs only in case both versions of the app are installed per-machine, since `FindRelatedProducts` apparently assumes per-user installation (because it runs before the user was able to pick one of the radio buttons and therefore there is no `ALLUSERS` propety set at the time it runs).

**How do I ensure that `FindRelatedProducts` is executed only after `ALLUSERS` was Published from the UI as specified by the user?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found I need to add the following to ensure `FindRelatedProducts` runs within the UI after the user made his choice:

```
<Publish Event="DoAction" Value="FindRelatedProducts">1</Publish>
```

From https://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg22960.html

I found it is not strictly needed to use the suppress attribute - it seems to work also without explicitly suppressing the action in the `InstallUISequence`.

Comment: It might be better to find a way to sequence it after the dialogs are finished. Or at least test that nothing goes wrong if the dialogs have Back buttons and you can hit that Next button multiple times and run FindRelatedProducts multiple times after the user may have changed between per machine and per user during the back and next dialogs.

Comment: True - it would be good to make sure the user does not go back chaning the install mode, but this is good enough for me for now. Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: @PhilDW if you have a working example how to properly sequence the RemoveRelatedProducts action after the dialogs are finished, I would be grateful to see them as an answer to this question.

Comment: You'd just need to sequence FindRelatedProducts after the Dialogs in the UI sequence - you should be able to say it's after="myFinalDialog".

Comment: I didn't find that the suppress was required either.

Comment: However, rather than put it in the InstallScopeDlg, I put it in the next dialog, the InstallDirDlg. That avoided any issues with the user clicking 'Back'.